# What happen if I remove /Dev files

Tags: linux, kernel, bios

I've removed windows from my PC and about to install Ubuntu from bootable USB.
I'd like to reset my PC completely but I found bios setting are still existing.
So I googled and found I can reset bios by

`modprobe nvram 
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/nvram`

Now I'm curious about what are those files in /Dev directory.

Can I delete them and install them from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

If you do so, the system will break. And as far as I remember, they are the main codes.

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/dev-fs.html

Check this link.